# Is it possible to pass arguments to PreferredSizeWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I declared `Scaffold`'s appBar as a variable out of scope.

```
PreferredSizeWidget originAppBar = AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: ....
```

This allows me to use it by assigning `originAppBar` to `appBar:`.

```
appBar: originAppBar,
```

However, I have included the following code in `originAppBar`.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Profile.route);
```

This is a function that requires a `BuildContext` and is not in the `originAppBar`.

Is it possible to have a PreferredSizeWidget with an argument? Like this C#;

```
//C# 
PreferredSizeWidget originAppBar = new PreferredSizeWidget(BuildContext context)

Widget build(BuildContext xontext){ 
....
    appBar: originAppBar(context)
....
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the definition was wrong.
The following is correct.

```
PreferredSizeWidget originAppBar(BuildContext context) {
  return AppBar(....
}

....

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: originAppBar(context),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GlobalKey - assign it to your widget

`Global keys uniquely identify elements. Global keys provide access to other objects that are associated with those elements, such as BuildContext.`

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Is it impossible to use `GlobalKey` only for `appBar`? In most of the samples on the net, `GlobalKey` is declared in the class, so I think that it can not be used with `PreferredSizeWidget`. I'm too new to study here, can anyone please tell me?